# Is there an Event that detects when all templates have been processed?

Tags: craft3, events

I'm working on a Content Security Policy and need to set an HTTP header after all templates have finished processing. Right now I'm doing that by calling a module variable at the bottom of the main layout template, but that feels brittle.

Is there an Event that can be used for this? I've looked through craft\events in the [API docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/) but don't see a good candidate.

Comment: Ah! Maybe EVENT_AFTER_RENDER_PAGE_TEMPLATE? Does "page template" equate to the layout that's being extended?

Answer (score 1):

Yahtzee.

```
use craft\web\View;
use yii\base\Event;

...

Event::on(View::class, View::EVENT_AFTER_RENDER_PAGE_TEMPLATE, function (Event $event) {
    // do things
});
```

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-view.html#event-after-render-page-template